# Obtaining JSON object values by name Java

Tags: java, json

My JSON Data looks something like this:

```
[
  "{\"pid\":\"1\",\"title\":\"New CEO announced\",\"titleirish\":\"CEO nua\",\"content\":\"Bernard Byrne has been announced as the new CEO. Rejoice!\",\"contentirish\":\"Is Bernard Byrne an CEO. B\\\\u00edg\\\\u00ed s\\\\u00e1sta!\",\"imageurl\":\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/scoiluiriada.ie\\\\\\/wp-content\\\\\\/uploads\\\\\\/2014\\\\\\/02\\\\\\/IMG_1781-150x112.jpg\",\"category\":\"News\",\"publishedby\":\"Andy\",\"modified\":\"2015-07-01 16:21:13\",\"buildings\":\"Bankcentre,Hume House,Time House\"}",
  "{\"pid\":\"2\",\"title\":\"New CTO pronounced\",\"titleirish\":\"CEO nua\",\"content\":\"Bernard Byrne has been announced as the new CEO. Rejoice!\",\"contentirish\":\"Is Bernard Byrne an CEO. B\\\\u00edg\\\\u00ed s\\\\u00e1sta!\",\"imageurl\":\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/scoiluiriada.ie\\\\\\/wp-content\\\\\\/uploads\\\\\\/2014\\\\\\/02\\\\\\/IMG_1781-150x112.jpg\",\"category\":\"News\",\"publishedby\":\"Andy\",\"modified\":\"2015-07-02 10:09:10\",\"buildings\":\"Hume House\"}",
   ....
```

So far I have the following code:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(allData); // allData = JSON String above
        JSONArray nitems = (JSONArray)obj;
```

This gives me an array of all the objects I want to parse. (it works perfectly)

Now, looping through this array, I would like to get the object member values.
Something like this:

```
nitems.get(0).getValueOf("title") // should return "New CEO announced"
nitems.get(0).getValueOf("titleirish")  // "CEO Nua"      etc.
```

This obviously doesn't work, what code do I use instead.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: What Error/Output do you get instead of the expected?

Comment: getClass doesn't accept String parameter. I'm just wondering what to use instead. I have tried creating new object from elements in the above Array, casting that to an array, and getting the elements from that, but I couldnt cast  this one to an array either.

Comment: do you use the `org.json library?`

Comment: yes, the nitems is working fine. I would just like to get the members of each nitems object by name

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Comment: You input technically is JSON. But it is only an array containing two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with help from some comments. Here is solution:

```
JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(nitems.get(i).toString());
System.out.println(obj2.get("title").toString());
```